# Flash / Php LCCS (now Influxis RTC) Uncaught exception 'RTCError'

Tags: php, apache, flash, apache-flex, lccs

I have a `Flex/PHP` application that uses `Influxis RTC` (ex Adobe LCCS service) in my localhost machine (I use `MAMP` on a Mac) everything works ok, but when the same application files are uploaded to a remote host (provided by Arvixe) I get this error:

```
$Revision: #11 $ - $Date: 2011/07/27 $ http_get: [my account path]?mode=xml&accountonly=true& Array ( [headers] => Array ( ) [readbuf] => Resource id #4 ) 
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'RTCError' in [my server path]/lccs.php:797 Stack trace: #0 [my server path]/lccs.php(670): RTC::http_get('[my account path]', Array) #1 [my server path]/lccs.php(259): RTCAccount->do_initialize() #2 [my server path]/index.php(31): RTCAccount->__construct('beta.ics...') #3 {main} thrown in [my server path]/lccs.php on line 797
```

Does anyone could give me any help with `PHP` settings?
Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

This is James from Influxis. Please drop us a email to ICS Support ( icssupport@influxis.com ) and we help you with getting it up and running.

Thanks,

James